# A way to fuse multiple find for the same array?

Tags: javascript

I am in the case where I use several find () on the same array.

Something like that:

```
const array = ['apple', 'pen', 'pear', 'pineapple', 'pen', 'banana']
const apple = array.find(el => el.equal('apple'))
const pear = array.find(el => el.equal('pear'))
const banana = array.find(el => el.equal('banana'))
```

This must be costly in computation time. And I wonder if it would not be more logical to use a function that returns several different responses ?

Is there a function in ES6 + that doing that ?

Something like that:

```
const array = ['apple', 'pen', 'pear', 'pineapple', 'pen', 'banana']
const [apple , pear , banana ] = array.find(el => el.equal('apple'),
                                            el => el.equal('pear'),
                                            el => el.equal('banana'))
```

Comment: You can use reduce() method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `.filter()` method like:

```js
const array = ['apple', 'pen', 'pear', 'pineapple', 'pen', 'banana']
const [apple , pear , banana ] = array.filter(el => el == 'apple' || el =='pear' || el == 'banana')

console.log( apple, pear , banana )
```

Comment: yeah, it works but it means that if what I'm looking for is in the right order.